# ffmpeg - output images in memory instead of disk

Tags: python, ffmpeg, pipe, disk

I've a python script which basically converts a video into images and stores them in a folder, then all this images are read and informations are extracted from them, then images are deleted. Since the writing images step is so slow and is apparently useless for what I need, I would like to store images somehow in memory instead of the disk, read this images from there and doing my operations, this would speed up my process a lot.

Now my code look like: 
1st step:

```
ffmpeg -i myvideo.avi -r 1 -f image2 C:\img_temp
```

2nd step:

```
for i in range(1, len(os.listdir(IMGTEMP)):
#My operations for each image
```

3rd step:

```
for image in os.listdir(IMGTEMP):
        os.remove(IMGTEMP + "\\" + image)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [MoviePy](http://zulko.github.io/moviepy/):

```
import moviepy.editor as mpy
clip = mpy.VideoFileClip("video.avi")
for frame in clip.iter_frames():
    # do something with the frame (a HxWx3 numpy array)
```

Comment: Amazing it seems to work! Only 2 questions, why imageio require and download ffmpeg 32 bit when I have a 64 bit system? And is there a way to control the frame to select? Like in ffmpeg I can select 1 frame each second using -r 1, I would like to do the same thing in MoviePy.

Comment: I don't know about imageio, it looks like an unwanted behavior, maybe open an issue in the project's page. For the fps just write clip.iter_frames(fps=1)

Comment: Something strange happened. When I try to run now the script I got the error "import moviepy.editor as mpy, ImportError: No module named editor". Funny thing is that I haven't changed anything, moviepy is still installed and the script is still the same.

Answer (score 1):

The short version is that you could use ramdisk or [tmpfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs) or something like that, so that the files are indeed actually stored in memory. However, I'm wondering about your "operations for each image". Do you really need an image file for them? If all you're doing is read their size, why do you need an image (with compression/decompression etc.) overhead at all? Why not just use the FFmpeg API, read the AVI file, decode frames, and do your metrics on the decoded data directly?

Comment: I calculate the hash of image using [imagehash](https://github.com/JohannesBuchner/imagehash/blob/master/imagehash/__init__.py) library which need the actual image to do on it some operations (resize, compare pixels etc.) Do you have any example for the methos you suggested? I really don't know anything about it.

Comment: You can calculate the hash of images using -f framecrc or -f framemd5 instead of -f image2. As output file, give a file to write hashes to that file, or - to write them to stdout.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [PyAV](https://github.com/mikeboers/PyAV). (There is [documentation](http://mikeboers.github.io/PyAV/), but it's rather sparse.)

It looks like you could just open a video, and then iterate over the frames.

Comment: I'd suggest also [ImageIO](http://imageio.github.io/) and [MoviePy](http://zulko.github.io/moviepy/), which can also do that.

Comment: Seems interesting, as soon as i manage to install it I will try. I keep getting build errors.

Comment: Building stuff on ms-windows can be difficult and frustrating because it lacks the tools and infrastructure that UNIX variants have.